# cant import library flask python

Tags: python, flask

I am doing tutorial https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/. I am importing library

```
from tumblelog import app
```

it doesn't work. Also I can't find this library `tumblelog`.
the structure of my directory: C:\flask-tumblelog-master\tumblelog\
that is where my project located.

Comment: what is tumblelog in this context I don't understand .

Comment: Try `pip search tumblelog` and see what's you're looking for.

Comment: So this github project: https://github.com/rozza/flask-tumblelog appears to be (at least) related to what you are doing. It imports different libraries, and I don't know which one you haven't included will fix the error you get... but one of them should....

Comment: In which file you try to do it and the full error log?

Answer (score 2):

From the tutorial (bold added for emphasis):

> First, create a simple “bare bones” application. **Make a directory named `tumblelog`** for the project and then, add the following content into a file named `__init__.py`:

`tumblelog` isn't something you install. It's something you make. Make the directory and put the application code inside it.

Comment: Yes I have named my directory tumblelog and project as well. it shows me error

Comment: this is where is located my manage.py file: C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\tumblelog

Comment: from tumblelog import app is highlighted

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/flask-tumblelog-master/tumblelog/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    register_blueprints(app)
  File "C:/flask-tumblelog-master/tumblelog/__init__.py", line 13, in register_blueprints
    from tumblelog.views import posts
ImportError: No module named 'tumblelog'

Comment: highlighting means that Python doesn't recognize this statement

Comment: Based on your update you have a single file, `manage.py`. The excerpt I quoted specifically mentions `__init__.py`. Your application won't work until you add that.